# Given several $a_i$-$r$ paths in a planar graph how ``balanced" of a tree rooted at $r$ can I make?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

Suppose I am given distinct nodes $a_1,a_2,.., a_l, r$  and several $a_i$-$r$ paths $P_i$ in a planar graph $G$.

I wish to construct a tree $T$  connecting $a_1,a_2,.., a_l, r$  that minimizes the maximum over all $a_i$, the number of nodes bounded by the cycle formed by $P_i$ and the $a_i$-$r$ path in $T$

how minimal can I make this quantity (number of nodes bounded by the cycle formed by $P_i$ and the $a_i$-$r$ path in $T$)  relative to the maximum number of nodes that lie inside a cycle of $P_i \cup P_j$?